# I want my log In pop up to not show the scroll bar on the bottom

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, popup, scroll

So my code is this:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function myPopup2() {
window.open( "http://aunabzzzolution.weebly.com/log-in.html", "myWindow", 
"status = 0, height = 185, width = 300, resizable = 1" )
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="button" onClick="myPopup2()" value="  Log In  ">
</form>
</body>​
```

Here's an [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/WGymw/)

And I dont want the scrollbar to appear at the pop up. How??

Also if you want to see a live example, go [Here](http://aunabzzzolution.weebly.com/) (top left corner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to HTML/CSS code of the pop-up, you could simply add `overflow: hidden` to its body style.

Comment: I added at the html, but nothing happened.. You see I use weebly, and the css is for every singal page I have. :/

Comment: May i save the html on a file, upload it and then cp its url? The weebly's css wont be applied to the code right?

Comment: I didn't get what you were trying to say. So, there's no way you can change CSS of your page?

Comment: No.. Only if i load the page d=from external link. eem i uploaded an html file of the file, but when the pop up box appears, it prompt me to download the file and it doesnt loads.. So how to load the external html??

Comment: I created another site for the login form on weebly. I will try if it works with the overflow on he css:)

Comment: Yay fixed :D http://aunabzzzolution.weebly.com/ at the top left, press  login and see :D